# How to group records with positive payment totals only?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by

I've got this SQL query in my Rails 5 / MySQL powered application that groups **people** by the sums of their **payments**:

```
@people = Person.joins(:payments)
                .where(:payments => {:date => @range})
                .order("sum_payments_total DESC")
                .group(:id)
                .sum("payments.total")
```

I am using the result to build a pie chart using Chart.js.

The problem is that pie charts need positive numbers in order to make sense.

So in the query above, is there a way group only those **people** whose **payments.total** is grater than 0?

I could probably change the array accordingly but it would be nice to do it in SQL.

Comment: In where clause add WHERE PAYMENTS > 0.

Comment: and HAVING clause in your query like HAVING PAYMENT>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use having

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

```
@people = Person.joins(:payments)
                .where(:payments => {:date => @range})
                .order("sum_payments_total DESC")
                .group(:id)
                .having("payments.total > 0")
                .sum("payments.total")
```

I have not tested so I don´t know if my addition to your code is completely ok

Comment: It works when I do `.having("sum_payments_total > 0")`. Thanks!